# How to write coda files from mcmc objects?

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I have looked everywhere and I still cannot find a function in R that can help me write a coda file from a mcmc object. I am running OpenBUGS in R using the R2OpenBUGS package:

`output <- bugs(...)`

Then after some manipulation, I am left with an object called `chain_mat` that has class `mcmc`. This object is rather long (over 2 million rows) so I want to create a coda file to save the draws. I am aware you can create coda files directly from the `bugs` function but I need to do some manipulations first, before I can create the file.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `mcmclist2coda` in the sirt package?

Comment: @gjabel I was able to write my own function using the function you provided in your comment, thank you!